# How to change crash message in android(if possible)

Tags: android

I am wondering if it is possible to change the crash message for android?("unfortunately app has stopped") I haven't found anything that says you can(which I don't think you can), I am just making sure by asking on here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the system message as stated by @Nuno Gomes but you can suppress the original message and display a message on your own or start some activity.

You can define an exceptionhandler that catches all uncaught exceptions in app class and show a message box from there

```
public class MyApp extends Application  implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mPreviousUncaughtExceptionHandler;
    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mPreviousUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        try {
            // Do your stuff with the exception
            Log.e(Global.LOG_CONTEXT,"LogCat.uncaughtException " + ex, ex);
            // show user defined messagebox

        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* Ignore */
        } finally {
            // uncomment this to let Android show the default error dialog
            // mPreviousUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

the app must be declared in the manifest

```
<manifest ...>

    ...

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp" ...>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

On my android-4.4 i use this code to write a chrash log file

Answer (score 2):

That message is a system message, it's outside the app scope, so no you cannot change it