# Is UncaughtExceptionHandler set application wide?

Tags: android, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I have set an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, so that I can write out stack traces to disk when my app crashes. I set this handler like this:

```
if (!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() instanceof CustomExceptionHandler)) {
         exceptionHandler = new CustomExceptionHandler(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString(),
                null, this);

     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
}
```

where `CustomExceptionHandler` implements `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. I keep the instance in my `Activity`, so I can use it for some other functionality (deleting the stack traces, retrieving them, etc).

I call the above piece of code in the `onCreate` of my `Activity`, but it seems to only trigger the first time any `Activity` is run.

I see the `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` call is static though, does that mean I can only set that handler only once in my app? Or can I set it per thread?

Answer (score 0):

From docs

```
 * Sets the default uncaught exception handler. This handler is invoked in
 * case any Thread dies due to an unhandled exception.
```

Yep, this handler is global and you need to set it once per app

Answer (score 0):

> Is UncaughtExceptionHandler set application wide?

Yes. If you set it in an activity and the activity is destroyed the handler code in the activity may not exist any more.

I have set the handler in the Application-onCreate (not in the Activity) so it works for all Activities that belong to the Application to write crash logs.

For details see [How to change crash message in android(if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867043/how-to-change-crash-message-in-androidif-possible/45867325#45867325)

[Here](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/util/LogCat.java) is the gpl-v3+ code for my crashlogger that writes logcat entries to file.

It is initialized in [Application.onCreate](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/AndroFotoFinderApp.java) like this

```
public class AndroFotoFinderApp extends Application {
    private LogCat mCrashSaveToFile = null;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mCrashSaveToFile = new LogCat(this, Global.LOG_CONTEXT, HugeImageLoader.LOG_TAG,
                PhotoViewAttacher.LOG_TAG, CupcakeGestureDetector.LOG_TAG,
                FotoLibGlobal.LOG_TAG, ThumbNailUtils.LOG_TAG, IMapView.LOGTAG,
                ExifInterface.LOG_TAG, ImageMetaReader.LOG_TAG);
    }
}
```

where the constants  `Global.LOG_CONTEXT`, `HugeImageLoader.LOG_TAG`, ...
are android logging tags of different moduls of my code use like this

```
Log.d(HugeImageLoader.LOG_TAG, "some log message from modul HugeImageLoader)
```